# Symfony 1.4.18 and PHP 5.4 compatibility

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Is the latest Symfony version (1.14.18) supposed to run properly with PHP 5.4?

I've just upgraded to PHP 5.4 locally and multiple sites that have previously worked fine are now throwing the following error when trying to load any page:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method sfCoreAutoload::register() in C:\dev\projects\my_site\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 4
```

The path to the sfCoreAutoload class is fine but for some reason it treats it as if it didn't exist at all.

Comment: The latest symfony version is 2.1, I wouldn't stick with 1.4 anymore.

Comment: @moonwave99: This isn't for new projects but existing projects written in 1.4.

Comment: It works perfectly for me with both versions. Try deleted cache, specially project_autoload.cache.

Comment: @glerendegui: thanks for your answer. Reinstalled everything and eventually found the reason - answer below.

Comment: depending on what you want to do, 1.4 may still be a good choice. fabpot himself stands by it, see https://twitter.com/fabpot/status/192949239276511233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue so will just answer here for the benefit of anyone else facing the same. The culprit was APC. The latest "stable" version of the pre-compiled APC (3.1.9) didn't work with Symfony 1.4.18 + PHP 5.4.4, but using the APC beta (3.1.12) does work.

Comment: but how did you installed new APC? i'm using xampp server 1.8 and have some problems? but i don't know how update APC? 
since updating my xampp server (1.7>>1.8), i'm no longer able to run my projects, it says: "You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected." but it has permissions and everything works with older xampp sever.

Comment: Well, you can always check if APC is the cause by disabling it in your php.ini (extension=php_apc.dll). You can update APC by just dropping in another version of the php_apc.dll file into xampp/php/ext. You'll find different versions through Google (don't have the link at hand, sorry). Remember to restart Apache after updating.